# Confused about a step in a proof; For a closed set, $F$, and a point $x\in F$, there's an open interval around $x$ and contained in $F$?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

[image]

I've underlined the step in the proof that isn't clear to me.

I know what I said in the title is wrong; but I'm not really sure what motivates the step that I underlined.

This is taken from Royden, 4th edition, page 66.

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Edit: To be more clear, I'm confused about how we get an open interval fully contained in $F_i$ which also contains $x$. Why must $F_i$ fully contain an open interval that also contains $x$?

Comment: Your question does not match your title.

Comment: The complement of a closed set is open.

Comment: Well, the intersection of an open interval and $F$ is open relative to $F$.

Comment: I've added an edit to my post to clarify what I'm confused about. Sorry if it was unclear.

Comment: Royden **never** asserts that $F_i$ contains an open interval.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To say that $g$ is continuous on $F$ means that for any $x \in F$ and for any $\epsilon>0$ there is some $\delta >0$ such that if   $|y-x|<\delta$ **and** $y \in F $ then $|g(y)-g(x)| < \epsilon$.

In the above case, we have $x \in F_i$, and since the $F_k$ are
disjoint and closed, the set $\cup_{k\ne i} F_k$ is closed and
disjoint from $F_i$. Hence $x \notin \cup_{k\ne i} F_k$ and so
there is some interval $(a,b)$ containing $x$ such that $(a,b) \cap (\cup_{k\ne i} F_k) = \emptyset$.

Hence if $y \in F \cap (a,b)$ we must have $y \in F_i$ and hence
$g(y) = g(x)$.

So, given $x \in F$ and $\epsilon>0$, we can find some $i$ and an interval $(a,b)$ as above such that $x \in (a,b)$ and $(a,b) \cap F \subset F_i$ (in particular we have $g(x) = a_i$).

Now choose $\delta>0$ such that $B(x,\delta) \subset (a,b)$, then if $|y-x| < \delta$ **and** $y \in F$ we have $y \in (a,b) \cap F_i$ and so $g(y) = a_i$ (and so $|g(y)-g(x)| < \epsilon$, of course).

Comment: Well, I did show continuity above. Let me elaborate a little.

Comment: Okay. I think I see.

So the argument rests on the fact that $\cup_{k\neq i}F_k$ are closed, and thus the complement is open. Correct?

Comment: @Bears: That is correct.